# How to set eth0 MAC address in Vagrant with the VMware provisioner?

Tags: vagrant, ethernet, mac-address, vmware-workstation, vmware-fusion

Vagrant relies on VMware (Workstation and Fusion) to generate the MAC address of eth0 (the first and default ethernet interface) on a guest being deployed from a box.

I would like to fix this MAC address so it is static and not regenerated each time the VM is recreated so that the VMware DHCP service can assign it the same IP address each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that the VMware DHCP service will assign an IP address to a specified MAC address by editing `vmnetdhcp.conf` which has different [locations depending on OS](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-10/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-04D783E1-3AB9-4D98-9891-2C58215905CC.html). Place an entry at the end of the file replacing the hostname, MAC and IP with desired values:

```
host hostname {
    hardware ethernet 00:0A:AA:AA:AA:AA;
    fixed-address 192.168.1.1;
}
```

Restart the VMware DHCP service to load these changes.

In your `Vagrantfile` use the following settings to configure the default network interface:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.define 'hostname' do |hostname|
        hotname.vm.box = box
        hostname.ssh.host = '192.168.1.1'
        puppet.vm.provider :vmware_fusion do |v, override|
            v.vmx['ethernet0.addressType'] = 'static'
            v.vmx['ethernet0.address'] = '00:0A:AA:AA:AA:AA'
       end
       puppet.vm.provider :vmware_workstation do |v, override|
            v.vmx['ethernet0.addressType'] = 'static'
            v.vmx['ethernet0.address'] = '00:0A:AA:AA:AA:AA'
        end
    end
end
```

Next time the virtual machine is brought up with `vagrant up` it will assigned the static MAC and recieve the same IP address from DHCP.

Other [vmx keys](http://sanbarrow.com/vmx/vmx-network-advanced.html) could also be manipulated for `ethernet0` using this method.

Comment: If VMware Workstation or VMware Fusion is updated, this file may be reset and the changes put back.